# My Operating System stucks during booting everytime

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I am a new user and using 20.04 LTS.

I am using Hp Envy 15 core i7 and i have built-in Geforce Graphic Card 740M.
I installed this OS 7 days from today it worked perfectly ok four days but After that it stucks during boot everytime.

I saw many videos on Youtube in witch they told to write "nomodeset" or "nouveau.modeset=0" i applied both commands but found no result.
[image]

Comment: How exactly it is stuck? On which screen? What is displayed on screen? Is ts here some kind of error or message? It can be broken in many ways.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: when i open computer the ubuntu screen opens as i attached in my previous question, and spirally round courser appears and after some seconds courser disappears and blank screen remain and nothing happen..

Answer (score 0):

Press "STRG + ALT + F1" and you can possibly see what your Laptop is trying to do. There he will display further output which could be useful to see where the problem is. Possibly a hardware resource or he is try to do something or a defect hard-drive or a wrong setting. Did you changed something before?

If you see something on the screen where he stuck, make a photo to identify this later.

If you start your laptop the next time,then press |⇧| or Esc during the boot process before he is showing the Ubuntu-Logo. So you will see the option to boot into the normal Ubuntu or the recovery-Ubuntu-Sytem, where you can make some changes. Lock at the photo what was wrong or show us the moment where the boot-process was stopped.